# Latex equation with unequal space

Tags: latex, equation

I have typed code for set of equation but I am not sure the problem as there is different spacing for it from the left, can you help me correct this uneven spacing

```
\begin{eqnarray}
    L(x) &=& T_e(x) - T_i(x)\\
    \label{eq:latencymsg}
    L_{avg} &=& 1/N \sum_{n=1}^{N} L(x)\\
    \label{eq:latencymsgavg}
    \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{b-a}&\text{for $L(x)\in[a,b]$}\\
    0&\text{otherwise}\\
    \end{cases}\\
    \begin{cases}
    0&\text{for $L(x)<a$}\\
    \frac{x-a}{b-a}&\text{for $L(x)\in[a,b)$}\\
    1&\text{for $L(x)\ge b$}
    \end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}
```

[image]

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: do not nest `cases` into `eqnarray`, just use two more `equation` environments.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
    L(x) &=& T_e(x) - T_i(x)\\
    \label{eq:latencymsg}
    L_{avg} &=& 1/N \sum_{n=1}^{N} L(x)
    \label{eq:latencymsgavg}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{b-a}&\text{for $L(x)\in[a,b]$}\\
    0&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
    0&\text{for $L(x)<a$}\\
    \frac{x-a}{b-a}&\text{for $L(x)\in[a,b)$}\\
    1&\text{for $L(x)\ge b$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Labelng is not the same because I do not have chapters 1, 2 and 3 in my [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/49683), but:

[image: equations aligned]

Eventually, add two more `label`s to cite equations number three and four.